# Chaning participants attribute while creating an asset

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to change a property of participant after they create an asset?

I want to create a network in which a person gets x points after they add an asset to the network. Could anybody guide me?

I am using Hyperledger Composer.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Nothing, actually. I thought of doing it from logic.js but suppots only transactions, and I want to manipulate over asset.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is, when you add value to one asset then that automatically reflect another asset.

Using an **AssetRegistry** with **update** function. you can update an asset.

you can refer this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/runtime-assetregistry#update).

Answer (score 0):

in your bna you can create a different types of entities, participants, assets etc.

you can have multiple of each. each one of them is identified via a unique identifier.

now, since you use composer, you probably noticed that you get asset endpoints. You will need to ignore those, basically, do not use them. You can create assets via a transaction, in which case you can use your js file to change a property of a participant as well.

some documentation can be found here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/runtime-assetregistry

of course you will need to find the right one for the version of hyperledger you are using but it should give you an idea of how to do it. So you create your asset, then via the registry you load your participant and then you change what you need.

there might be another solution as well, I haven't tried it myself but it might work. In Hyperledger you can use events. Maybe you can raise an event when an asset is created, in which case it doesn't matter how you create it and inside that event, you change the participant.